# How to set/check cookies in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie and also check if it is there, does anybody have any sample code for this? All I found was the [TTPCookieStorage class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but it would be helpful if I could see an implementation example.

Answer (score 4):

Only the server of an HTTP connection should be setting cookies. It does this with a Set-Cookie field in the headers.

The cookie storage you linked handles all NSURLConnection cookie action (both getting and setting) and generally -- you shouldn't change the cookies yourself. If you want to override, you can't use NSURLConnection and will need to use a CFReadStreamRef and handle the communication and build a CFHTTPMessageRef manually.

You *will* need to handle cookies if you're implementing the server side of HTTP communication.

If you're implementing a server using CFHTTPMessageRef, then:

```
NSDate *expiryDate = /* set some date value */

CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(
    response,
    (CFStringRef)@"Set-Cookie",
    (CFStringRef)[NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"SomeCookieName=%@;Path=/;expires=%@",
            someStringValue,
            [dateFormat stringFromDate:expiryDate]]);
```

where `response` is the `CFHTTPMessageRef` you're using for the reply. You can use `CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields` and get the object for key "Cookie" to extract cookies from the client in a CFHTTPMessageRef header.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're looking for: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are for web pages.  If you want to display web pages, use a UIWebView.  If you want to store persistent data, use NSUserDefaults.  If you want to parse cookies sent from a server, use NSURLConnection and parse the headers.  If you want to see what cookies have been set by a UIWebView running in your applicaiton, use NSHTTPCookieStorage.

> NSHTTPCookieStorage Class Reference
>
> These cookies are shared among all
>   applications and are kept in sync
>   cross-process.

That is only true if your application runs as root on the iPhone.

Comment: What do you mean by "run your app as root on the iPhone"? iPhone-Apps are sandboxed by default, aren't they?